# SQL - Select rows based on filters for two different relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a daily menu for my users based on all the meals I have available for their hubs **today**. Here's what my database looks like:
[image: schema]

Here's exactly what I want the query to retrieve:

```
Give me the emails of the users who have daily_email set to True with the information of their company and the hub their company belongs to. 
For each user, I need to see the meals available for them along with the information of the restaurant this meal belongs to.
```

So far I've tried using `INNER JOINS` and mixing all tables together then doing the filters I want. It gave me what I wanted but with terrible performance. I'm not mainly looking for the optimal solution, but at least one that has acceptable performance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way than joining all tables based on their relations:

```
select u.email, c.name, h.name, m.name, r.name
from users u
inner join companies c on c.id = u.company_id
inner join hubs h on h.id = c.hub_id
inner join hubs_meals hm on hm.hub_id = h.id
inner join meals m on m.id = hm.meal_id
inner join restaurants r on r.id = m.restaurant_id
where u.daily_email
```

Make sure that all the foreign keys are indexed.

Comment: Thanks, this is at least better than what I had. I also added another condition at the end to filter on dates. Appreciated!